# Validate an array of objects for duplicate key value pair depending on other key value pair among other objects of array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, key-value

```
let currentFruit = "apple"
let Array = [{fruit:"apple",locale:"US"},
        {fruit:"orange",locale:"US"},
        {fruit:"banana",locale:"US"},
        {fruit:"apple",locale:"US"},
        {fruit:"orange",locale:"IT"},
        {fruit:"apple",locale:"IT"},
        {fruit:"banana",locale:"IT"},
        {fruit:"orange",locale:"IT"}
        {fruit:"apple",locale:"IT"}]
```

Have "currentFruit" from object which has it locale to be "US".
I want to validate if "currentFruit" exists in the "Array" with same locale "US" to set the flag to "true" else if "currentFruit" exists in the "Array" with different locale would be "false".

```
for (let i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
            if (Array[i]["fruit"].toString().toLowerCase() === currentFruit.toString().toLowerCase()) {
                this.uniqueFruit = true;
                break;
            } else {
                this.uniqueFruit = false;
            }  
        }
```

The above code evaluates if "currentFruit" exists in the array of objects.But,how could i validate if "currentFruit" exists in the array with same locale "US".

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz Result is to set flag.i mean "uniqueFruit" to true or false with a condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the comparison of the `locale` to your loop as follows:

```js
let currentFruit = "apple"
let Array = [{fruit:"apple",locale:"US"},
        {fruit:"orange",locale:"US"},
        {fruit:"banana",locale:"US"},
        {fruit:"apple",locale:"US"},
        {fruit:"orange",locale:"IT"},
        {fruit:"apple",locale:"IT"},
        {fruit:"banana",locale:"IT"},
        {fruit:"orange",locale:"IT"},
        {fruit:"apple",locale:"IT"}]

console.log(validate(Array,currentFruit,"US"));
console.log(validate(Array,currentFruit,"FR"));

function validate(arr, currentFruit, locale){
     for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
          if(arr[i]["fruit"].toLowerCase() == currentFruit.toLowerCase() && arr[i]["locale"] == locale)
               return true;
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property for wanted fruits and add a property depending on the `locale` property.

```js
let currentFruit = "apple",
    locale = "US",
    array = [{ fruit: "apple", locale: "US" }, { fruit: "orange", locale: "US" }, {fruit: "banana", locale: "US" }, { fruit: "apple", locale: "US" }, { fruit: "orange", locale: "IT" }, { fruit: "apple", locale: "IT" }, { fruit: "banana", locale: "IT" }, { fruit: "orange", locale: "IT" }, { fruit: "apple", locale: "IT" }]

array.forEach(o => {
    if (o.fruit !== currentFruit) return;
    o.uniqueFruit = o.locale === locale;
});

console.log(array);
```